# Assistance with MySQL Query - Omitting, Grouping?

Tags: mysql

Doing a bit of investigation and writing a query against a logs db.

I've joined a number of tables to bring back the data that I need, but i'd like to clean it up a bit.

The query returns all the users and which features they have enabled on their account.

Here is what i'm trying to do to clean it up:

Their is a column called 'actions' which has two states, 'added' and 'removed'

If a user feature has an action of 'removed' then I want to not show any of the rows for the same feature for that user which are also marked as 'added'

Is this possible?!

Here is what I have so far:

```
select users.id as site_id, users.company_name, feature_log.featurecode, feature.minimum_account as feature_type, users.account_type as site_type, account_types.name as account, feature_log.action, feature_log.time
from users
inner join
    feature_log
    on users.id = feature_log.siteid
inner join 
    feature
    on feature_log.featurecode = feature.featurecode
inner join account_types
    on users.account_type_INC = account_types.id
where feature.minimum_account != 0
    AND feature.minimum_account > users.account_type
    AND users.status = 'Y'
    ORDER BY feature_log.time DESC
```

Thanks for any support!

Comment: How big is the `feature_log` table? Is performance important in the context of this query? (I can see you may need to use a dependent subquery or a left join, which may be terribly slow)

Comment: Only around 8K rows, performance isn't really important as it's just for one off investigation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, in order to "mute" all the features, that have been "removed" at any point in time for a given user, you can add a (left) join on the following subquery:

```
SELECT DISTINCT users.id as siteid, feature_log.featurecode, TRUE as mute_feature
FROM users
INNER JOIN feature_log ON (users.id = feature_log.siteid)
WHERE action = 'removed'
```

This will be the list of features that a given user disabled at some point in time. Then in your query's `WHERE` clause, you'd add a filter like so:

```
AND NOT IFNULL(mute_feature, FALSE)
```

Essentially, that'd bring your whole query to be:

```
select users.id as site_id, users.company_name, feature_log.featurecode, feature.minimum_account as feature_type, users.account_type as site_type, account_types.name as account, feature_log.action, feature_log.time
from users
inner join
    feature_log
    on users.id = feature_log.siteid
left join (
    SELECT DISTINCT users.id as siteid, feature_log.featurecode, TRUE as mute_feature
    FROM users
    INNER JOIN feature_log ON (users.id = feature_log.siteid)
    WHERE action = 'removed'
) as muted_features ON (feature_log.siteid = muted_features.siteid AND feature_log.featurecode = muted_features.featurecode)
inner join 
    feature
    on feature_log.featurecode = feature.featurecode
inner join account_types
    on users.account_type_INC = account_types.id
where feature.minimum_account != 0
    AND feature.minimum_account > users.account_type
    AND users.status = 'Y'
    AND NOT IFNULL(mute_feature, FALSE)
    ORDER BY feature_log.time DESC
```

Comment: Romain, if we ever cross paths, i'm buying you a beer! Thank you, this worked perfectly!

Comment: @adamtor45 I will remember this :) Anyway, this wasn't that hard - you'll get to do this on your own with just a little bit of practice.